# ActionBar change color of menuitem button when pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How to change color of menuitem button when it  pressed. I use SherlockActionBar but when it pressed it changes color to one that it not really good for my design. I need to change this color.

**Updated:**

The point is when I set drawable i placed on background and when button is pressed then change of bckground near my drawable changes. I can change the drawable, but background will still change it`s color to ugly one.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the background by setting the `actionBarItemBackground` attribute in your theme. This should be a state-list drawable which reflects states such as pressed and focused.

Comment: Using the theme generated here, it does set the actionBarItemBackground but still shows the original theme http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=sherlock&theme=dark&actionbarstyle=transparent&backColor=2D2D2D%2C100&secondaryColor=151515%2C100&tertiaryColor=3F3F3F%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100

Comment: Does it have both `android:actionBarItemBackground` and `actionBarItemBackground` in the theme. You need both as per the ABS docs.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be working now, I was making changes to my theme for the TextView color must have temporarily broken something.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you change the icon to a new icon when you click the menu item.
Ok so, first create a member variable and get a reference to the menu item in onCreateOptionsMenu().

Then when you click the item set the item to a new drawable (of your colour)

```
MenuItem mMenuItem;

.....

menu.add("Map").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM  |     MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
mMenuItem = menu.getItem(0); 


......
mMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_set_as);
```

Hope this helps.